# Inserting text in Ace Editor via Protractor throws error

Tags: protractor, ace-editor

I am trying to run an automated test and one of the steps of a test case is to clear the Ace Editor and insert text in it.

Earlier I had regular content editable DIV and I was able to insert text in it but not anymore after switching to Ace Editor.

All I am doing is calling "clear" method on the element and then "sendText" on it.
I tried adding "click" method before clear to make sure Ace Editor does have the focus and it did bring the focus to Ace Editor but it still throws an error that element should be user-editable to clear it.

I also tried putting a sleep of 5s before clearing it just in case, Clearing is getting triggered before Ace makes the div contenteditable.

Here's the exact error to be precise.

```
Failed: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question.
Since Ace Editor is not native browser element, i looked up on api that they are provide. Seems like you can use `.selection.selectAll()` and `.removeLines()`

If i would be you - i would try to call JS function, that selects everything, and calls .removeLines()

```
await browser.executeScript(`editor_reference.selection.selectAll(); editor_reference.removeLines()`) // variable will be diferent, depending how you connected editor object
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor

You can see how it works right on their example page (https://ace.c9.io/) - execute this in browser console, editor should get cleared:

```
editor.selection.selectAll(); editor.removeLines()
```

Answer (score 0):

send `ctrl-a` keys (`cmd-a` on mac) to select all before typing, so that clearing is not needed

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience working with Ace editor before. I used demo ace editor from https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html to find a solution for the issue you are facing.

I tested the below piece of code in the demo Ace editor and it works fine.Not sure how the ace editor is implemented in your application.You can try it in your application and provide your thoughts.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove($(".ace_active-line")).click()
.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.COMMAND, "a"))
.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE)
.sendKeys("content in line1\ncontent in line2")
.perform()
```

If you are using windows machine then use `protractor.Key.CONTROL` instead of `protractor.Key.COMMAND`.

Hope this will work fine!